# Sorting a sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using Jquery UI to get users to sort a list. I have a button to show answers if they want, which will put the list in order, based on ID. The function that sorts the list is:

```
function show_order() {

    var elems = $('#sortable').children('li').remove();
    elems.sort(function(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);
    });
    $('#sortable').append(elems);
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE (11) - with no error in console.

See http://jsfiddle.net/bvacK/ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sort` expects you to return a value less than 0 (`a` less than `b`), 0 (equal) or a value greater than 0 (`a` greater than `b`). Simply returning the result of a `>` comparison will yield a boolean. Change your code accordingly:

```
return parseInt(a.id, 10) - parseInt(b.id, 10);
```